# PHP user permissions - best practice?

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

What is the best practice to manage user permissions with PHP/MySQL?

What I have currently is a column in the users table that is called 'permissions', with a string that is compared for certain pages.

```
if($_SESSION['permissions'] == 'Administrator' || $_SESSION['permissions'] == 'Moderator'){
// do stuff
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to get this accomplished in a simpler, easier way. Any recommendations?

Comment: Read some good tutorial on ARO & ACO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you managing 'mySql' permissions?  Do you mean your controlling actions in your website that are capable of performing database actions, or you're literally needing database access rights management?

If its via the web, you could incorporate something like [Zend Framework's ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html) if you're looking to get that in depth, or any other existing permissions system built in PHP.

Comment: I'm talking about website permissions - for example similar permissions set up for popular CMS's such as Joomla, etc.

Comment: +1 for Zend ACL. I started designing an ACL library for our company framework, then looked at Zend ACL, then stopped.

Comment: Ok, for website permissions, then yes... I'd check out Zend's ACL

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that helped out a lot!